# f(x,y) - Some clarifications needed.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

so I have run into this problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7xgr.png

I was unable to solve it and when looking over the answer some of it seemed unclear to me, could someone please clear it up for me?

Answer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uYr1.png

I could really use some explaining on:
1.
The f(x,y) part really threw me off, i'm not exactly sure what it means to have f(x,y) is that like f(x) and f(y) is == to the equation or does it mean something entirely different.

2. Their second step showing that the boundaries of the rectangle arise from those terms. Where did the other part of the equation go 0.o. How did they manage to spot this? Did they graph the different X values from the examples and work out that it is x = sqrt(A) ? Would that work?
3. The third step, where the values of x and y were solved in terms of A.

Explanations would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: $F(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, the first argument you give it goes in place of x in the equation and the second goes in place of y...

Comment: Hint: if $a\times b \times c=0$ then at least one of a,b,c is zero

Comment: That helped a lot danimal. Thank you!